# Where is the traffic view for IoT orchestrations?

Tags: activity, iot

I am trying to find out how to turn on the orchestration log/traffic view just like presented on trailhead: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/iot_basics/units/iot_learn_how_iot_works_unit

Any ideas?

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use the following process:

For orchestration:

- From Setup, enter IoT in the Quick Find box, then select Orchestrations.
- Select an orchestration, and click Tracker button.
- Enter a key value, and click Start Tracker.

For logs:

- From Setup, enter IoT in the Quick Find box
- Select Activity Log.

**References**

- [Troubleshoot New Orchestrations in Salesforce IoT](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=iotx_troubleshoot_orchestrations.htm&type=5)
- [Monitor Orchestration Activity in Salesforce IoT](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=iotx_monitor_orchestrations.htm&type=5)